# Getting rid of backslashes

Tags: php

I use mysql_real_escape_string() before interting information in the database, but when I want to show the data from the database, ' is replaced with \'.
So how can I get rid of that backslash? Is there a function that reverses mysql_real_escape_string()?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't add backslashes to the final data. There must be something else going on, like double escaping or magic quotes

Comment: Right. Try disabling magic quotes in php.ini or with [this snippet](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). If that doesn't work and you need a quick fix, you can use `stripslashes`.

Comment: I guess you've got `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled - turn it off. By the way, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as a database-access layer instead of `mysql_*()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **There is NO [built-in] function to reverse mysql_real_escape_string.**
2. If you have only quotes but not linebreaks escaped - it is not mysql_real_escape_string to blame.
3. Instead of stripping, you apparently have to make your code **not to add them**.
4. There are 2 possible reasons for the slashes to appear:

   - `magic_quotes_gpc` is turned on. **[Just turn it off.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)**
   - some extra-wise-data-sanitize function in charge. Get rid of it.
5. Just to make sure: not whatever "information" but only **strings** (query parts enclosed in quotes) have to be escaped. For the any other query part escaping is useless and **[you have to find another way to protect them from SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/285587)**

Answer (score 2):

You should off the [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) although `mysql_real_escape_string` does not add any backslash in the database that it is used just to escape the string.

However you can use the [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove them but the more elegant solution is to `off` the `magic_quotes`

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` does add slashes, they're just removed by MySQL. The problem is that `mysql_real_escape_string` is escaping slashes (which presumably came from magic quotes) with more slashes.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, that is just for escaping string and not stored in database