# Get rid of all back slashes in php

Tags: php, wordpress

woe be me...

I don't know whats happened but suddenly slashes are being added to strings in the request object.

I'm passing ID = "1" to the server;

I make up the where clause.

```
$where = array( 'ID' => $_REQUEST['ID']);
$result = $wpdb->update($this->the_table, $dbfields, $where);
```

Somehow slashes are being added and thusly the where clause doesn't match.
How can I get rid of the rascals?
I've tried

```
$where = array( 'ID' => stripslashes($_REQUEST['ID']));
```

and

```
$where = array( 'ID' => stripslashes_deep($_REQUEST['ID']));
```

---

PHP Version 5.2.17

### `php.ini`

```
magic_quotes_gpc  
On  On

magic_quotes_runtime  
Off Off

magic_quotes_sybase  
Off Off
```

Any help much much much appreciated.

UPDATE----------------

I've turn magic_quotes_gpc  off but still no joy.

if I hard code this

```
$where = array( 'ID' => "1");
```

It works fine.

However using this -

```
$id = stripslashes($_REQUEST['ID']);
$where = array( 'ID' => $id);
```

no updates are made.

If I echo out $where.

It looks like "1" - no problem.

Head scratching stuff! Worked fine a day ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting rid of backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482233/getting-rid-of-backslashes)

Comment: `stripslashes()` not working?

Comment: You should probably be using `$_GET` or `$_POST`, FYI.

Comment: @rockerest Whilst I generally agree with you, there's nothing wrong with `$_REQUEST` so long as you understand the data sources and order of precedence

Comment: Doing this on the client side gave me temporary relief parseInt(vo.ID)

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `magic_quotes_gpc`.

Some methods of achieving that here - http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: thanks again Phil. This is proving to be a bit of a pain. I've stripped the slashes - now when I do $id = stripslashes($_REQUEST['ID']);
$idi = (int)$id; $idi = 0 but the string is "1" hmmmm I wonder why it doesn't convert.